# Knitr takes several minutes before processing the Rmd file

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am using knitr to create html document but the compilation takes several minutes **before** processing the file and takes like 2 minutes after the process to show the output.
[image]

Nothing appears for minutes and then :

[image]

I have tried different computers and different YAML using the most basic :

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---
```

or

```
---
title: "xxx"
output: rmdformats::readthedown
---
```

I had issues with knitr and I found this solution :
https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/4462

But now it takes forever to compile a document.

I am using files on a local network (quite bad performances), I don't know if it can explain my issue.

The code in chunks can be executed in less than 1 minute.

**How to improve the compilation of .Rmd files ?**

Comment: You don't say what front-end you are using, but it sounds as though it's the front-end that is spending the time.  To test this, try running `rmarkdown::render("yourfile.Rmd")`, and see if that has the same delay.

Comment: I suppose by front-end you meant UI, it is RStudio Version 1.2.1335, I have the same issue when using the classic R console (RGUI) when I use the code `rmarkdown::render("yourfile.Rmd")`

Comment: In that case I think you're going to need to post a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be related to the network (which causes a lot of issues by the way).

My .libPaths() is located in a network drive, so I suppose rmarkdown is loading slowly.

When I use a configuration with local files, I dont have this issue.